# spark dataframe explode function error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to use the explode function on a DF, I just write the code like the document:

```
    case class Url(url:String)
    val temp3 = temp2.explode($"urls"){
        case Row(urls:Array[String]) => urls.map(Url(_))
    }
```

However , it came out:

```
error: not found: value Row
```

The DF temp2 is like:

```
temp2.printSchema()
root
 |-- userid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- urls: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add the following import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```